# How to add cordova plugins now that they are renamed and ported to npm?

Tags: node.js, cordova, meteor

For example, I want to add the camera and file Cordova plugin. According to the official documentation, I should do

```
meteor add cordova:org.apache.cordova.camera@0.3.1
```

However, the plugin has been renamed cordova-plugin-camera, how can I add the newest compatible version? I know I need to use 0.3.1 because the documentation said that. But how do I know which version to use for the cordova-plugin-file?

Comment: you can install the plugins using the old org.apache... they have a remapping system that will fetch the latest version even if you use the old syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor will support new cordova npm plugin registry in next [release](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md#meteor-mobile).

For time being, you could add the latest camera plugin from github tarball:

```
meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-camera@https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/tarball/437cf3d93a2c0c841d38c6c80472b2ba118f372a
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did what you said. But to use the tarball url I need to know which commit (version) to use. For example, when I install the newest cordova-plugin-file, the compiling on Xcode failed. How do I know which version to use?

Comment: You can get a list of version [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/releases). Click on commit hash and replace `commit` with `tarball` in the url. I use the latest version and Xcode compiled successfully.